# Joomla logging fails from time to time

Tags: php, logging, joomla, path

I'm always struggling with Joomla and the log settings. I tried:

"logs", "/logs", "\logs", "./logs", "../logs".

The last one worked the best, but still very annoying that I have to worry about what will break tomorrow.

The last joomla update to 3.3.1 resulted in this:

> **Warning**:  fopen(../logs/error.php) [function.fopen]:     failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/...root/libraries/joomla/log/logger/formattedtext.php** on line **234**

in that file, line 234:

> fopen($this->path, 'a')

Which makes me wonder why it doesn't contain any prefix like the JPATH_BASE or whatever...

Does anyone know a good setup/solution to fix this recurring issue?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla management and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, you will probably get a better answer on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well probably the simpliest way would be to echo your `JPATH_BASE` somewhere (you might add `echo JPATH_BASE;` into your template for a second), then copy that path, and paste it into your logs path also adding `/logs`);

The final result should be something like this: `/var/www/website_name/logs/` (The path itself might be different, due to server configuration, OS and etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if just specifiying "logs" for the LOG directory does not work, then the

```
# RewriteBase /
```

has been changed from / to something else.

Having said that, if you add the absolute path to your Joomla site then that should work. You can check your absolute path by printing our $_SERVER .